# .NET Core not able insert data in cache when redis is setup on a port other than 6379

Tags: .net-core, redis

I have set up the redis server to run on a port 7000 (other than 6379). The redis services are running absolutely fine. However, my .NET Core application is not able to store the data in redis cache in this scenario. However, if I change the port to default 6379, then everything works perfectly fine.

Can you please suggest me what could be the issue?

Comment: What tools or libraries are you using to talk to redis? How have you configured those tools? Have you told them to use port 7000?

Comment: I'm using StackExchange.Redis via NuGet to connect to Redis. The config file used to create the service is correctly pointing to port 7000. My connection string for Redis in my code looks like "localhost:7000,abortConnect=false,allowAdmin=true"..

Comment: No sir... The config says  port: 7000

Comment: Oh my bad.. the connection string is "localhost:7000,abortConnect=false,allowAdmin=true"

I have updated above connection string

Comment: What currently happens? Do you get an error about there being no node available able to service the request? Does the `redis-cli -p 7000 ping` check work?

Comment: It returns me PONG

Comment: ok; that's a good start - it means the server is at least responding; so: what *exactly* happens in your code when you try to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibilities:

- check that your configuration string to SE.Redis (or any other library) tells it to use port 7000; since you mention SE.Redis in the comments, just using `"somehost:7000"` should be sufficient
- check that there isn't a firewall rule blocking you; a simple way to test this would be to use `redis-cli -h somehost -p 7000` at the command-line (ideally  on the machine that is struggling to connect, as the account that is struggling to connect) to connect to the server to issue a test command such as `ping` - note that this won't help if you have per-application firewall rules configured
- it could be a library bug, but I would consider that unlikely since there isn't anything very specific to .net core in this area, and the existing code certainly supports non-default ports (we use that all the time)

Comment: When I run my redis-cli, it is running on port 6379 because in the command prompt, I see 127.0.0.1:6379 (which seems to be the default setting). I however have setup another redis service to run on port 7000. So basically there are two services. I want to store data in the redis service running on port 7000. Can you please help me

Comment: @Shiva the `-p 7000` argument to `redis-cli` tells it to use port 7000; please try it

Comment: Hey buddy.. I think I found the issue. Since default redis cli was running on port 6379, i was not able to see my cached keys as connection string of redis was pointing to port 7000. Based on your suggestion, I changed the redis-cli to use port 7000 and then I noticed cached keys getting generated. Thank you so much @marc.. It was of great help

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. Since default redis cli was running on port 6379, i was not able to see my cached keys as connection string of redis was pointing to port 7000. Based on your suggestion, I changed the redis-cli to use port 7000 and then I noticed cached keys getting generated. Thank you so much @marc.. It was of great help. There wasn't anything wrong with the code. It's just that I was looking for keys on port 6379.

Comment: I'm glad you're all sorted :)